# N body simulation of earth sun and moon syste,

Tags: differential-equations

Im trying to model a system consisting of the orbital paths the Sun, earth and moon under the gravitational forces of one another.

```
Ecc = {0.01671022,0.00549};(*eccentricity*)
\[Mu] = {2.9591220823*10^-4, 8.8878*10^-10,1.093*10^-11} (*standard gravitational parameter of sun,earth and
moon in AU*)
r = {0.98329, 0.991954}(*initial postion AU*)
rx = {0.98329, 0.991954}(*x and y components of intitial position*)
ry = {0, 0} 
v = {0.0000303148,3.32854*10^-6}(*initial velocities of earth and moon*)
```

Im trying to use ND solve to solve the system.

```
planet = Table[NDSolve[{(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + (\[Mu][[j]] (x[t]))/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(
  3/2) + (\[Mu][[j]] (x[t]))/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(3/2) == 
 0, (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
  t] == -((\[Mu][[j]] (y[t]))/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(
   3/2)) - (\[Mu][[j]] (y[t]))/((x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2)^(3/2), 
x[0] == rx[[i]], y[0] == ry[[i]], Derivative[1][x][0] == 0, 
Derivative[1][y][0] == v[[i]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 365.2}], {i, 
1}, {j, 1, 2}]
```

This is a set of second order differential equations for the bodies in the xy plane(co planar). I'm wanting to use NDsolve to solve the 2nd order ODEs so that i can plot the earth and moons orbital paths.

NDSolve does solve the ODE's however when i think this is wrong.

For example for`x''[t]`

the values of `/Mu`need to be different for each 
equation.
Where j=1 for the sun and j=2 for the moon
Also the initial conditions for  the distance of the earth from sun and moon also need to be different

```
x[0]==rx[[i]], y[0]==ry[[i]]
```

where i=1 for the distance between earth and sun and i=2 distance between moon and sun.

i think im close to this working so any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: In documentation [page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulation.html) (section "Applications") for `NBodySimulation` you can find a similar example.

Comment: First change the second order derivatives to `x[i]''[t]`. Furthermore I'm wondering that your orbit ode are separated. I would expect a system of coupled odes which are applied to **one** NDSolve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I've chnaged this to coupled ODE's,
however this still is not working. i now get the error message: 
         
ConstantArray::ilsmn: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of ConstantArray[{TemporaryVariable$8141,TemporaryVariable$8142},-\[Infinity]].

I also changed it to x[i]''[t].
thank you.

Comment: Still you have a list of uncoupled NDSolve-commands. Perhaps it is easier to understand if you first define your system equations before passing them to `NDSolve`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I defined the ODEs before solving and it did work so i re-inserted them.  
NDsolve seems to work however, i dont think i shows the acceleration of the body due to the sun and the moons gravitational forces, i believe this is because of how the table function  uses my values of i and j but i cant be sure.

Comment: If I change the second  order derivatives (as recommended in my comment 11hours ago)  `planet` is evaluated without error message!